# Why are pointer events disabled when using Apple's pencil in Safari?

Tags: ios, ipad, pointer-events

I'm using [pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events) to build a multi-touch interface for web. If I use multiple fingers, each pointer captured as I'd expect. But on an iPad, if one of those pointers is an apple pencil, this stop behaving the way you'd expect. As far as I can tell:

- if the apple pencil is the first pointer down, other touches are ignored,
- if you're actively dragging with a finger, the apple pencil is ignored.
- etc...

I assume this is Apple trying to prevent accidental touches when writing, but is there a way to disable or ignore this?

```js
element.addEventListener('pointerdown', down);
element.addEventListener('pointermove', move);
element.addEventListener('pointerup', up);
```